# Django ModelForm ManyToManyField isn't able to update selected values

Tags: python, django

I am building my first project in Django 1.8 with python 3.4. I have the following model called Lid in models.py:

```
class Lid(models.Model):
    ...
    vereniging = models.ManyToManyField(Vereniging, blank=True)
```

I use the following ModelForm, forms.py

```
class LidForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Lid
        exclude = []
```

When I use this ModelForm to create a form to make a new object, a multiple select box appears and I am able to select multipe Vereniging objects. This is my view in views.py:

```
def add_lid(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LidForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Succes.')
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('leden:home'))
    else:
        form = LidForm()
    return render(request, 'leden/lid/addlid.html', {'formset': form})
```

When I want to edit my objects however, I am not able to change the selected selected Vereniging objects.

```
def edit_lid(request, lid_id):
    lid = get_object_or_404(Lid, pk=lid_id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LidForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=lid)
        if form.is_valid():
            nieuwlid = form.save(commit=False)
            nieuwlid.inschrijving_oras = lid.inschrijving_oras
            nieuwlid.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Success.')
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('leden:lid', kwargs={'lid_id': lid_id}))
    else:
        form = LidForm(instance=lid)
    return render(request, 'leden/lid/editlid.html', {'formset': form, 'lid': lid})
```

So this is basically my problem: when using a ModelForm, I am only able to set ManyToMany relationships when creating an object. I am not able to update these m2m relationships. Do you know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `save_m2m()`. From [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method):

> Another side effect of using `commit=False` is seen when your model has a many-to-many relation with another model. If your model has a many-to-many relation and you specify `commit=False` when you save a form, Django cannot immediately save the form data for the many-to-many relation. This is because it isn’t possible to save many-to-many data for an instance until the instance exists in the database.
>
> To work around this problem, every time you save a form using `commit=False`, Django adds a `save_m2m()` method to your `ModelForm` subclass. After you’ve manually saved the instance produced by the form, you can invoke `save_m2m()` to save the many-to-many form data.